# Background of Travel.SE in footer blends into background

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: Travel.SE footer]

The colour icon for Travel.SE in the footer blends into the background on our site (but not on others or out Meta, because they have a different background).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next production build.